# How to evaluate how well one group of curves fits the other?

Tags: math, curve-fitting, inversion

I need define a misfit function to describe the fitting situation of two groups of curves. The curves are recorded as arrays of points. Who has an idea or give me some hints?

The two groups of curves are like below, they may be very different or sometimes they're the same. If all the parts of the first one locates on the second, I would say the fitting is perfect. They have the same x-axis and y-axis.

The first is real-world data, the second is synthetic that comes from forwarding, I need to define a misfit/fitting function that I minimize or maximize to perform an inversion. Indeed, the second one is not its original format,  the synthetic data is a 2D array with a value for each (x, y)，then I pick the maximum and get these points as below.

**Appendix**:

I have a set of real-world data, which have the format like this:

x  y

---

1.1 1.2

3.1  2.3

...

I plot it then get some curves as the first figure.

These are data, if I want to perform a inversion, I'll do the forward simulation to get synthetics to compare with data. The synthetics I got are in the format like this:

x  y  value

---

1. 1.     3.4
2. 2.     1.2
3. 3.     5.6
4. 4.     1.2

...

2. 1.    -1.3
3. 2.    6.7

...

The second figure is the result that I pick the maximum value. Of course, it's better to use the raw synthetics.

The inversion needs a misfit/fitting function, I've no idea how to define it. If they're just some points that compose one curve and compared with the other curve, I can just do an interpolation and calculate the Euclidian distance. However, they're a group of curve now, and it's hard to define it.

[image: the first group of curves]
[image: the second group of curves]

Comment: What are you intending to use this algorithm for? If this is real-world data then what does it represent? Why do you want to match different curves of this type?

Comment: @cdo256 one is real-world data, the other is synthetics, I need to define a function that I minimize or maximize to perform an inverison. Indead, both of them are 2D dataset, I pick the maxmium values and get the two curves above.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I would use *the result of* some sort of [Iterative Closest Point (ICP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) to characterize the distance between the two point clouds (the distance would be, informally, the size of the transformation that will give you the best fitting). Basically, you assume that the red and blue points are in the same plane. Then,

1- You associate each blue point to its closest red point.

2- Find the translation/rotation that minimizes the sum of the distances between each blue point and its associated red point (this is simple minimization, you can do this via a simple Levenberg-Marquardt, though it seems overkill, Gauss-Newton shoud do it). That is, you will be solving

`argmin_{R,T} sum_i{norm2(b_i-R*r_i+T)}`

with `(b_i,r_i)` a couple of blue/red matches obtained at step 1. `R` is the 2d rotation matrix, and `T=[t_x  t_y]'` is a 2d translation.

3- Iterate throught these steps 1 and 2 until convergence.

This gives you a vector in `R^3`, which is of the form

`transformation=[angle translation_x  translation_y]`

Now, you can use `norm(transformation)` as a rough measure for how well the two curves fit each other. You should probably be careful about fixing the estimated angle in an interval like `[0,pi]` though.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I read some about ICP, there is a question: If the cloud of the red points are very different from the blue ones, what's the meaning of transformation (R, T)? Is the norm of it very large? Does ICP only work for those that have similar contour or shape? The shape of the blue ones that forwarding generates may be not similar with the red one.

Comment: Yeah... I admit, this was a bad idea (thanks for editing your question btw, the problem is clearer to me now). If the two point sets are too different, then I expect the ICP not to converge, so that could be an indicator of large differences.

Comment: The way I see it you need either to have some sort of descriptor, to compare the two sets, or you need to compute a transformation from one set to the other, but in a well... more sophisticated manner than in my ICP idea. As for the descriptor, it seems out of reach to me (unless maybe you train a convNet), so I think the second approach might be a safer bet.

Comment: Ps: can you provide a link to example data files so I can play a bit with them? I can't promess I'll find anything, but this is an interesting problem

Comment: Sorry for long time. I have tried ICP as you said. I only use translation and no rotation, because I think rotation is meaningless for this problem. The translation is performed only onto x-y plane. The result is fair, worse than I expect. Here is [example data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwpv0CqGaAW1M1NzU3VHSERmZWM?usp=sharing).

Comment: Yeah... ICP was not a good idea... I'll take a look at the data, thanks.